# android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) crash with realm-js and react native

Tags: android, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, realm

I am trying to integrate realm as stated in the docs. On Android I get the following error after trying to write something to a realm. The crash occurs exactly at the create function, and also only on Android

My code:

```
const myRealm = new Realm({path: 'settings', schema: [Settings.schema], schemaVersion: 1})

myRealm.write(() => {
 myRealm.create(Settings.schema.name, new Settings()); // CRASHES HERE
})


*the trace:*

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128 (SI_KERNEL), fault addr 0x0 in tid 10786 (mqt_js), pid 10722

2021-10-28 13:53:07.296 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-10-28 13:53:07.296 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-10-28 13:53:07.296 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-10-28 13:53:07+0200
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: pid: 10722, tid: 10786, name: mqt_js
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10134
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128 (SI_KERNEL), fault addr 0x0
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:     rax ffff000000000002  rbx 000077a4eec00000  rcx 000077a4e5f5c000  rdx 000077a4ee844330
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000000  r9  000000000000001a  r10 0000000000000000  r11 0000000000000246
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:     r12 000077a4ee844330  r13 000077a53383d201  r14 0000000000000000  r15 000077a52f2895b0
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:     rdi 0000000000000190  rsi e40077a4e9b88700
2021-10-28 13:53:07.297 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:     rbp 000077a4ee8a7b40  rsp 000077a52f288ee0  rip 000077a536e388d6
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000000005358d6  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/libjsc.so!libjsc.so (offset 0xc3000) (JSC::JSObject::setPrototypeWithCycleCheck(JSC::VM&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, bool)+342)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000000c515a  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/libjsc.so!libjsc.so (offset 0xc3000) (JSObjectSetPrototype+106)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000191e0e  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/librealm.so (BuildId: dd0e11db1b66b3f4fe08d49838e7f1bee268ee5d)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000191263  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/librealm.so (BuildId: dd0e11db1b66b3f4fe08d49838e7f1bee268ee5d)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000001e7133  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/librealm.so (BuildId: dd0e11db1b66b3f4fe08d49838e7f1bee268ee5d)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 00000000001c8a7b  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/librealm.so (BuildId: dd0e11db1b66b3f4fe08d49838e7f1bee268ee5d)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000000b71cb  /data/app/com.app.app--cvrLz6vselE5Gc5V1juDg==/lib/x86_64/libjsc.so (long JSC::APICallbackFunction::call<JSC::JSCallbackFunction>(JSC::ExecState*)+491)
2021-10-28 13:53:07.464 10845-10845/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 0000000000000026  <anonymous:77a4eedff000>
```